C# Message queues between threads and general threading woes
Before I start, I'll let you know that I'm still just learning (by doing) threading, and I think I'm missing some essential piece of the puzzle.
However, I am having a weird issue. The app I'm writing (no comments on how bad the code is, please) works. However, initially it did not update the UI (WPF). So following bits and pieces on various forums, I fiddled so that the work (currently just reading in a folder structure) does its job in a new thread. In the process, I tried using ConcurrentQueue to pass messages between the worker and the UI. This worked by polling (which I'd rather not do as it used a fair bit of CPU to poll regularly enough at times, but others go for ages without a change). So I found ObservableConcurrentQueue as a wrapper to ConcurrentQueue and set up what should be (I think) an event subscription. (on reading, there seems to be a thousand different ways to skin the messaging cat, this is the one that seemed to appear the most / easiest)
It should have worked, but I'm now getting "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' when the FolderCount goes to be incremented.
I'm not sure how or why a different thread suddenly now owns it when it was previously OK. The only thread I'm creating is the worker thread, which was (is?) successfully sending messages via the concurrent queue, and should not be running the code in question. From my interpretation, everything else should be on the same thread (when I created the subscription in the worker thread, it gave me this same error, but switching it to the MainWindow class/thread should have fixed it?).
Below are the relevant bits of code that should show what I'm doing wrong.  I have no doubt that I'm doing it "badly" and probably even trying to mix methodologies.
{
       public void SearchFolder(string path)
       {
           Task.Run(() => { SFolders(path); });    
           }

       private void SFolders(string path) 
       {
           if (Directory.Exists(path)) {
               _pm.Add(ProcessMessages.FolderCountAdd); // THIS IS WHERE IT CHUCKS A HISSY FIT
               
    // OTHER STUFF - rest of routine
            }
    // MORE STUFF
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow mw = null;
        public ProcessMessages pm = null;
        public Searching searching = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mw = this;
            pm = new ProcessMessages();
            searching = new Searching(pm, this);
            pm._queue.ContentChanged += OnObservableConcurrentQueueContentChanged;

        }

        private void OnObservableConcurrentQueueContentChanged(object sender, NotifyConcurrentQueueChangedEventArgs<int> args)
        {
            // Item Added
            if (args.Action == NotifyConcurrentQueueChangedAction.Enqueue)
            {
                int message;
                pm.Fetch(out message);
                while (message > 0)
                {
                    switch (message)
                    {
                        case ProcessMessages.FolderCountAdd: { FolderCount++; break; }
                        case ProcessMessages.FileCountAdd: { FileCount++; break; }
                    }
                    pm.Fetch(out message);
                }
            }
        }

    public class ProcessMessages
    {
        public ObservableConcurrentQueue<int> _queue = new ObservableConcurrentQueue<int>();

        public int Count => _queue.Count;

        public void Add(int message)
        {
            if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));
            _queue.Enqueue(message);
        }

        public bool Fetch(out int message)
        {
            return _queue.TryDequeue(out message);
        }

    }

}

It seems to me that the event handler and the UI should all be running in the same thread, so I'm not sure what's going on.
Thanks in advance to anyone/everyone who can expalain whats going wrong (even if it's fundamentally wrong from the ground up).

It is necessary to understand the activation mechanism of ObservableConcurrentQueue - what makes you think it is marshalling to the UI thread when invoking the event? I wouldn't expect that - I would expect either it gets called directly from the thread causing the change, or that it gets dispatched to the thread-pool. Neither of which will be the UI thread. I suspect you can fix this by just manually jumping back to the UI thread when you get the event - how to do that depends on the UI framework in question.

If this is the implementation you're using: it appears to be the first option, i.e. directly from the thread causing the change: https://github.com/YounesCheikh/ObservableConcurrentQueue/blob/master/ObservableConcurrentQueue/ObservableConcurrentQueue.cs#L140

THanks @MarcGravell.  I'm using WPF. I was guessing that it was the UI thread because that's where the subscription is was created (AFAIK). I'm adding the message in the worker thread.  How would I ensure I'm receiving in the UI thread? (OnObservableConcurrentQueueContentChanged is what is called when the trigger fires)

Yes. It's being enqueued from the worker thread. Hmm.... since it's meant to be all thread safe/aware, and is supplying an event for this, that seems weird that it would receive on the same thread, cause that kinda makes it useless, when it's whole purpose is cross-thread messaging...
So - is there a way to force the message fetch to happen on the UI thread? Or to switch to the UI thread?

a library can't usually do that because the mechanism is different per UI framework (although some indirect abstractions do exist), and it carries a significant performance penalty. The normal expectation is that if a receiver cares about the threading model, then the receiver deals with that. The only usual expectation on a thread-safe collection is that it doesn't corrupt itself when accessed concurrently, and: that seems fine here

As for the "how to do this in WPF": Dispatcher.Invoke

Your "constructor" is too busy (IMO). You should be "scaffolding" before that; or in the Loaded event (maybe).

@GerrySchmitz - can you give me more info about what you mean by scaffolding?

@MarcGravell - I got lost with Dispatcher last time I tried (over a year ago - but again, missing some secret sauce). However, I'll put on my big-boy pants and try again. :)  Thanks.

'Scaffolding" is anything that can or needs to be done before the main event; e.g. downloading / building files for the UI; or "searching".  After all is said and done, there may be no reason to display said Window. In any event, "crashing" in the constructor is not a good idea; too many other elements depend on it.

So this is where I get confused with Dispatcher.Invoke (I am probably doing something stupid). I am invoking from the worker thread with Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => FoldCount++));, and it correctly tells me that "FoldCount" doesn't not exist in this context (it's in the mainwindow context).  I have never been able to find anything that explains (clearly, to me), what code goes in the UI thread and what goes in the worker thread to make this work. I always end up with something that is not in the right context, which this is meant to alleviate.

So, you essentially want the background thread to signal to the UI that it should be updated?
The great thing is that there is already a queue for that! All UI frameworks I know about work around a message queue. You put a message on this queue by calling Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or just invoke. This will call the provided delegate on the UI thread at some later time.
But you don't need to dismiss polling out of hand. If updates are frequent it might be more efficient to just use a timer to check for updates, and update the UI as a batch operation. Polling every 100ms or so should only use a tiny amount of CPU.
I have never heard about ObservableConcurrentQueue, but it is generally important to read the documentation for any types you are using, especially with regards to thread safety. It is documented as thread safe, but does not mention anything synchronization to the UI thread. Some classes allow you to optionally specify a synchronization object, like a dispatcher or ISynchronizedInvoke, but these tend to be UI framework specific. Since ObservableConcurrentQueue does not seem to have any dependencies on any UI framework it probably do not support any such synchronization.
In the general case of using queues to communicate between non-UI threads you should probably take a look at BlockingCollection. This lets a worker thread simply loop around .GetConsumingEnumerable(), and the worker thread will automatically block when there are no items to process, no need for polling. I would also take a look at channels and Dataflow for higher level abstractions around threading. You should also be familiar with async/await, since that is the modern approach to most threading tasks.

It seems to me that the event handler and the UI should all be running in the same thread, so I'm not sure what's going on.

This is very easy to verify. Just place a break point in the event handler and inspect what thread it is running on.

I'm still just learning (by doing) threading

Thread safety is not very suitable for "learning by doing". It is very easy to write code that almost always works. If you are unlucky your code will pass all tests, only to fail silently during some critical operation, resulting in incorrect results and a very expensive cleanup, possibly including lawsuits. You need to familiar with the hazards and how to protect against them.

thanks for filling out the details. I'll give those docs a read and see how I go.

after re-reading, BlockingCollection seems to work the wrong way around. I need to consume on the UI, and this blocks the UI.  So back to retrying Dispatcher.Invoke

So this is where I get confused with Dispatcher.Invoke (I am probably doing something stupid). I am invoking from the worker thread with Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => FoldCount++));, and it correctly tells me that "FoldCount" doesn't not exist in this context (it's in the mainwindow context). I have never been able to find anything that explains (clearly, to me), what code goes in the UI thread and what goes in the worker thread to make this work. I always end up with something that is not in the right context, which this is meant to alleviate.

@Dion Anything that updates the UI needs to run on the UI thread. If you are using MVVM that means any properties the UI binds to.  I'm not sure how your code looks, but maybe you wanted  () => mainWindow.FoldCount++ ? If you are unfamiliar with delegates you might want to read the programming guide chapter about them

I've read that, but I'm honestly none the wiser. I kinda got it going, but I've had to pass mainWindow to the thread so that it can reference mainWindow.dispatcher.Invoke and mainWindow.FoldCount. It still had the error about existing without doing this, but it seems like overkill? All the examples I see don't need to do this, so I'm guessing I must have something fundamentally wrong.

@dion there is a Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher you can use on the UI thread to get the dispatcher. But you might want to consider just using async/await, possibly in combination with Progress. This should take care of the threading issues for you, since await resumes in the same "context", and Progress<T> takes care of the dispatching.

I still have to pass Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher to the worker thread, though... Is this the case or do I have something wrong somewhere? Note, this is the worker sending info back to the UI, which seems to be what the dispatcher is for, so it seems weird that I have to pass it around (and even when I use the above, it can't "see" FoldCount, unless I also pass that to the worker thread, which is why I still think I'm missing some "magic sauce" somewhere...

@Dion passing a dispatcher, or equivalent, sound fairly normal to me. See for example Timer.SynchronizatingObject. ISynchronizeInvoke does essentially the same thing as a dispatcher.  Not sure what you mean by FoldCount however.
